# How to avoid different capture group numbers in a regex?

Tags: regex, if-statement, regex-group

I'm trying to capture an IP address in a log and revert on a hostname if the address is 0.0.0.0.

Here are some examples of logs:

```
Foo bar ip=0.0.0.0 baz host=YOLO-PC foobar bazinga
```

In this case, I want "YOLO-PC" because IP is 0.0.0.0

```
Foo bar ip=12.23.34.45 baz host=FOOBAR-PC foobar bazinga
```

In this case, I want `12.23.34.45`.

Here's what I tried:

```
ip=(?:0\.0\.0\.0|(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)).*?host=(?(1).|(\S+))
```

It works, but when IP is 0.0.0.0, it creates a second group and the program behind it can't fetch group #2, only group #1.

How can I do this? Put it all in only one group? Is there a better solution?

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: It sounds to me that the simplest way to do this is by just capturing *two* groups, one with the IP address, and one with the hostname, and then have the "program behind" do a simple check whether the IP address equals 0.0.0.0 and use the hostname instead, if so. Is there anything that speaks against this approach? (Regex is great, but it is not suitable for everything.)

Comment: There's no way to put different parts of the regexp in the same group. You need to do what @O.R.Mapper suggests, do it in the application language.

Comment: If you use your current regex and simply concatenate the 2 capture groups (one of which will always be empty) in the environment/language you're using, then you'll get the value you want.

Comment: Also, @Gael's comment is really important, as this may depend on the regex engine. At least the engine used by [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/) recognizes the `(?(` toward the end of your expression as a syntax error and requires `(?:(` instead. So do [RegViz](http://regviz.org/) and [this regex tester](https://www.regex101.com) when set to JavaScript mode, while your expression is processed without any complaints while set to Python or PHP mode.

Comment: I'm using Python but I am forced to use the regex engine for technical reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unclear from your question which environment/language/regex flavour you're dealing with. But PCRE regexes actually let you do this with the `(?|some(capture)|another(capture))` syntax:

```
ip=(?|0\.0\.0\.0.*?host=(\S+)|(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

You can see from the [debuggex visualisation](https://www.debuggex.com/r/OXJN6rorIKkto0tY) that both groups are numbered **1**. And on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dE0rX9/1) you see the captures on the right.

Alternatively (if you're not using PCRE), I guess you could do this. It's less strict, but works in most every engine. You're current regex isn't particularly strict with the IP format (allowing numbers higher than 255, etc) so maybe this is not an issue for you.

```
ip=(?:0\.0\.0\.0.*?host=)?(\S+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/-ohpfope2m9FiALP)

Comment: Damned PCRE regexes. Is there something they can't do?

Comment: @AndreiVajnaII I know right?! I hear they're GREAT for parsing HTML too! `</sarcasm> <!-- please don't ever attempt that -->`

Comment: Thank  you so much! I'm using python, so I can't use the PCRE engine but it's a very good thing to know. The second regex is perfect. (Unfortunately, I can't use python directly to extract the right field).

Answer (score 1):

The number of groups on your result is equal to the number of `( )` groups in the regex. And the order you reference them is the order the opening parens appear in the regex. Some of the groups might not match and be empty.

So in your case, you will always have two groups. Group 1 is the non-zero ip and group 2 is the host-name. If the IP is 0.0.0.0, then group 1 will be empty. If not, then group 2 will be empty.

Can't you just check in your code which group is empty and use the other one?

Answer (score 0):

Use an alternation, which attempts left-to- right:

```
(?<=ip)(?!0.0.0.0)\S+|(?<=host=)\S+
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/Q6ThXDpbMl)

This matches only your target input due to using look arounds. A negative look ahead decided not to use the ip if it's all zero.

Just pick only the *first* match.

Comment: If the log lines are in one giant file, you're gonna wanna search with the `global` flag on, in which case this regex would find the `host=\S+` regardless of whether a non-0's ip has been found. (also unnecessary escaping in `\\S`, probably copy-pasta.

Comment: @funk double escape was my java experience  kicking in. But my regex is designed to use only the first match, and log with newlines (which I've only ever seen).